# How to get one String of dictionary that used as key from [String:Bool] in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
var markedDays: [String : Bool] = [
    "Sun" : true,
    "Mon" : true,
    "Tue" : true,
    "Wed" : true,
    "Thu" : true,
    "Fri" : true,
    "Sat" : true
]
```

Is there a way to use one string from my keys? Like `Sun` for example?
I need to compare it to another `String`.

Comment: Do you want to compare the value ?

Comment: I need to use the string.

Comment: can you explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve? then i'm sure someone can help... :)

Comment: I need to use the string values like Sun or Mon by my ditionary
Is there any way like Array[0] or something?

Comment: I cant use markedDays[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the keys of a dictionary like so:

```
let arrayOfKeys = Array(markedDays.keys)
```

Or if you are fine with a `LazyMapCollection` you can just use `markedDays.keys`

To access a specific day just plug in the proper index.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys and sort it by

```
let keys = markedDays.keys.sort()

// Get the key
keys[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is unordered collection, why don't you just use Array instead of Dictionary:

```
let markedDays: [(String,Bool)] = [ ("Sun",true), ("Mon",true), ("Tue",true), ("Wed",true), ("Thu",true), ("Fri",true), ("Sat",true) ]

let day = markedDays[0].0
```

Comment: Sure, you can change the value like:  `markedDays[0].1 = false`